# Select all items within ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am currently working on an Android project. I am using a ListView and using a context action bar and I am successfully selecting each item and showing a count of how many items have been selected within the list view.

Within the context bar I have a menu option for `Select All` but I don't know how I can make sure that every item within the list view is selected.

I can't seem to find anything on Google, anything about this type of thing and selectable ListViews seem to be very well hidden.

Comment: are you using custom adapter? some code which you made needed?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can check listview items one by one:

```
for ( int i=0; i < listview.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
   listview.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

If you only want to select what is on screen, then use `listview.getChildCount()`.

If you are using fragments, you will need to use `getListAdapter().getCount()`.

Comment: `listView.getChildCount()` won't work because it will return only the current drawn items only which might not be all the items in List given by the adapter.
Use `getListAdapter().getCount()` instead.

Comment: VipulKumar is right! You can also use listview.getAdapter().getCount() when not using list fragment.

Answer (score -1):

In android, listview item layout have many different default layout for selecting list item. You can use from the default layout or you can also create your own layout for list item. You can use

> Android.R.Layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice

to select more than one list item from the listview. For more reference see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.layout.html)

Comment: This does not address the original question.
The question is to programmatically select all the items in the ListView